# How to share data between components and provide it for a plotly chart

Tags: angular, plotly

Let me explain first what the working part is in my project:

`dataframe.component`: A button is emitting an event which calls a function `Initdf()` which initiates a service which retrieves JSON data from my backend API. I map two values from this data and assign them to arrays. `dfClose` and `dfDateTime`.

With these two arrays I want to feed a `plotly.js` chart in `plotly1.component`

I'm trying to achieve the data sharing between the components with `@Input()` and `@Output()` properties.

What is not working:

In my plotly1.component, I imported the onChanges method to listen to updates on the data (when button is clicked), but I get tons of repeated error messages:

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
```

I cannot complete the onChanges method because the angular doc is not detailed enough for me. I can't help myself with it alone.

dataframe.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { RestServiceDfinit } from '../../services/rest-df-init.service';
import { DfIndicatorService } from '../../services/rest-df-indicator.service';
import {Plotly1Component} from '../plotly1/plotly1.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dataframe',
  templateUrl: './dataframe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dataframe.component.scss']
})
export class DataframeComponent implements OnInit {

  df_array: any = [];
  tabVal:any = [];
  tabKey:any = [];
  df_standard_tab_order: any;
  toggleAdd: boolean = true;
  toggleDelete: boolean = true;

  @Output() dfClose:any;
  @Output() dfDateTime:any;


  constructor(private restService: RestServiceDfinit, private indicatorService: DfIndicatorService) {}//, private plotly: Plotly1Component) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {  }

  Initdf() {
    this.restService.postTickerGetDf().subscribe((response) => {
      this.df_array = response;
      this.dfClose = this.df_array.map((x: any) => x.Close);
      this.dfDateTime = this.df_array.map((x: any) => x.DateTime);
      
      .....
```

plotly1.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import {Plotly1Service} from '../../services/plotly1.service'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plotly1',
  template: '<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout"></plotly-plot>'
})


export class Plotly1Component implements OnChanges {


  public graph:any;

  @Input() dfClose:any;
  @Input() dfDateTime:any;

  constructor(private plotlyService: Plotly1Service) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.fill_data();
    }
   
  fill_data() {
    this.graph = {
      data: [
          { x: this.dfDateTime, y:  this.dfClose, type: 'scatter', mode: 'lines', marker: {color: 'blue'} },
        
      ],
      layout: {width: 1320, height: 600, title: 'test Plot'}}}}
```

Is it the right path to go with onChanges? How to I complete it?

Update: I skipped the plotly.component for testing and tried to get the data from `setData` in dataframe.component.ts in a `div` :

```
  Initdf() {
    this.restService.postTickerGetDf().subscribe((response) => {
      this.df_array = response;
      const close = response.map(x => x.Close);
      const dateTime = response.map(x => x.DateTime);
      this.mappedData.emit({
         dfClose: close,
         dfDateTime: dateTime
      });
      this.setData(this.mappedData);
    
  setData(mappedData:any) {

    this.dfClose = mappedData.dfClose;
    this.dfDateTime = mappedData.dfDateTime;

    this.graph = {
    data: [
        { x: this.dfDateTime, y:  this.dfClose, type: 'scatter', mode: 'lines', marker: {color: 'blue'} },
      
    ],
    layout: {width: 1320, height: 600, title: 'test Plot'}}
```

in dataframe.component.html I tried these variations:

```
  <div (mappedData)="setData($event)">{{graph}}</div>
  <div (mappedData)="setData($event)">{{mappedData}}</div>
  <div >{{graph}}</div>
  <div >{{mappedData}}</div>
```

It also doesn't work. In the best case I see `[object Object]`

Comment: An @Output is ususally an EventEmitter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. It works well with my initial idea to use the `OnChanges` lifecycle hook.

dataframe component ts:

```
  Initdf() {
    this.restService.postTickerGetDf().subscribe((response) => {
      this.df_array = response;
```

dataframe html:

```
<app-plotly1 [df_array]="df_array"></app-plotly1>
```

plotly1 component ts:

```
@Input() df_array:any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.dfClose = this.df_array.map((x: any) => x.Close);
    this.dfDateTime = this.df_array.map((x: any) => x.DateTime);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you didn't understood the @Input() and @Output() worflow.
The @Output() it's an EventEmitter which has to emit a value in order to receive it on the parent component. You don't even need two outputs. You should use one output which emit an object with your needs.

```
// in your child
@Output mappedData = new EventEmitter();
```

And then in your function you're doing something like:

```
// in your child Initdf() function
const close = response.map(x => x.Close);
const dateTime = response.map(x => x.DateTime);
this.mappedData.emit({
   dfClose: close,
   dfDateTime: dateTime
});
```

And then you'll catch these events in your parent component.

```
// in your parent html file
<app-dataframe (mappedData)="setData($event)></app-dataframe
```

Then in your parent component you can do your job with the data.

```
// in your parent ts file
setData(mappedData) {
  // here you have access to mappedData.dfClose and mappedData.dfDateTime
}
```

Second of all, you should start to use types instead of so many 'any'. It's a lot easier to prevent bugs.
And that's pretty mutch what do you need. You can delete these @Input's. You don't need them because you're getting your data through the @Output from your child.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer! I don't understand the `setData(mappedData)` function. Where do I have to place it? Everything you mention happens in the parent component. What about the constructor class in child `plotly1.component.ts`? It stays emtpy?

Comment: Editted a little bit my answer, maybe it's clear now

Comment: I think you are mistaken what's parent and child. plotly1.component should be child component. I've applied your code but now I get an error `Property 'setData' does not exist on type 'DataframeComponent'.` Please check my updated question how I used `setData`

Comment: I'm not mistaken anything, but maybe I didn't made myself clear. You can use this example for a reference and adapt it for your needs. Here's a full-flow of @Output usage: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vo95au?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-comp%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: It doesn't work. I had to switch parent/child because in my project the parent is emitting. Nonetheless, there's no button or anything in my child component like in your stackblitz example to call `setData`. Anyway , thanks for your input!

Comment: I realise now by reading other posts and spending hours trying to work out your solution, that your answer is misleading. Your solution will never work because you mistake parent and child in my project and I can't just "adapt" it to my needs because it works differently to emit from parent to child

Comment: I just gave you an example how the output mechanism works. I didn’t tell you which are your parent and which are the child. But fell free to do what you want